# Как реализовать подобную кнопку на CSS

Tags: css, css3

Возможно ли реализовать данную кнопку средствами CSS?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да можно.Следующий вопрос))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
button {
  border: .5em solid transparent;
  padding: .5em;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, blue 0, blue 100%),
    linear-gradient(to right, red 1em, pink 1em, pink calc(100% - 1em), red calc(100% - 1em));
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>My button</button>
```